# How do I reply to a message only if it was from a DM in discord.js v14?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want my bot to reply only if the message was sent via DM, not on any of the channel's server.

These are my intents and partials

```
const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    IntentsBitField.Flags.Guilds,
    IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildMembers,
    IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildMessages,
    IntentsBitField.Flags.MessageContent,
    IntentsBitField.Flags.DirectMessages
  ],partials:[
    Partials.Channel,
    Partials.Message
  ]
});
```

And this is the code im trying to use to read DMs. I got it from a tutorial but I cant find the channel object when I log the message.

```
client.on('messageCreate', async (message) => {
    
    // Check if the message is a direct message (DM)
    if (message.channel.type === 'DM') {
      message.author.send('Message Received');
    }
  });
```

Any ideas?

I dont get the "Message Received" message when I send a dm but if i remove the dm verification i get the reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`message.guild` will be `null` inside a DM; this is one way to check if the message is from a DM.

```js
if (message.guild === null) return;
```